# AVR Assembly - Calling a macro within a macro (Arduino Uno)

Tags: assembly, arduino, avr, gnu-assembler

I am learning AVR assembly on an Arduino Uno. I came across a compiler error while writing my program, and it seems that I am misunderstanding the proper implementation of macros. I am attempting to call a macro that consists of a list of other macros, and I keep getting a compilation error that's hinting toward the compiler not understanding or recognizing the macro. For example:

```
Within tftMain.s:

#include "avr/io.h"
#include "tftVars.s"
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0

.global tft_reset

tft_reset: 
    SET_WRITE_DIR
    CTL_INIT
    CS_IDLE
    RD_IDLE
    WR_IDLE
    RESET_IDLE
    WRITE_CMD
    RET
```

```
Within tftVars.s:

.macro PIN_HIGH port, pin ; (port, pin)
    SBI @0, @1
.endm 

.macro CS_IDLE         
    PIN_HIGH CS_PORT CS_PIN 
.endm

.macro SET_WRITE_DIR
    IN R16, DDRB 
    OR R16, BMASK 
    IN R17, DDRD 
    OR R17, DMASK
    OUT DDRB, R16 
    OUT DDRD, R17
.endm

.macro CTL_INIT 
    RD_OUTPUT
    WR_OUTPUT
    CD_OUTPUT
    CS_OUTPUT
    RESET_OUTPUT
.endm

...
```

So as seen within the code, I have a file `tftMain.s` which includes the file `tftVars.s`. The compiler error looks like this:

```
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: bad expression
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: `,' required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: constant value required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: garbage at end of line
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: bad expression
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: `,' required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: constant value required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: garbage at end of line
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: bad expression
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: `,' required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: constant value required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: garbage at end of line
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: bad expression
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: `,' required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: constant value required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: garbage at end of line
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: bad expression
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: `,' required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: constant value required
src\tftMain.s:30: Error: garbage at end of line
src\tftMain.s:31: Error: bad expression
...
```

This is on repeat for every line that calls a macro. I feel like my problem boils down to formatting- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would have expected the default `.S` file name extension for an assembly language source file containing C preprocessor directives, not `.s`. But your buildsystem might specifically compile `.s` sources with `-x assembler-with-cpp`, so that would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Within macro `SET_WRITE_DIR`:

```
.macro SET_WRITE_DIR
    IN R16, DDRB 
    OR R16, BMASK 
    IN R17, DDRD 
    OR R17, DMASK
    OUT DDRB, R16 
    OUT DDRD, R17
.endm
```

Misuse of `or` - should have used `ori`. Beginners mistake!

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth after almost 2 years since you posted the question. In case someone else hits this problem (as I did), this is the kind of syntax that worked for me on `MacOS, Arduino IDE 2.3.2`:

```
#define CS_PORT PORTA
#define CS_PIN  0B11

.macro PIN_HIGH port, pin // (port, pin)
    SBI &port, &pin
.endm

.macro CS_IDLE         
    PIN_HIGH CS_PORT, CS_PIN 
.endm
```

Here's a snippet of the generated assembly code:

```
  CS_IDLE
 180:   13 9a           sbi     0x02, 3 ; 2
```